# JQuery not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery function, which works in Chrome, but not in Firefox, Does anybody have any idea, what went wrong ?

This function is used to fill a text box with default values. The code logic is correct, as it works correctly in chrome.

```
$('#filler').change(function(){
//Logic here    
var Row = document.getElementById("node-0");
var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
var size=(Cells[2].innerText);
var chr=document.getElementById("filler").value;    
var fillertxt="";
for (var i=0;i<size;i++)
{
  fillertxt+=chr+chr+" ";
}       
if(!/[0123456789abcdef]/ig.test(chr))
    {
         alert("Do use Hexadecimal characters!");   
    }
    else
    {
        $('#input').val(fillertxt);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try using JQuery instead of $. and better you use all JQuery selectors for elements.

Comment: can you be more specific about "not working", please. Is the .change function invoked in ff or does the logic inside produce a certain error?

Comment: firebug is your friend

Comment: Do you use firebug, if so check console and try to debug.

Comment: The filler function is not executing the logic given. It is working in chrome, but firefox it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox uses the W3C-compliant `textContent` property, and not `innerText`, which is not supported in Firefox.

```
$('#filler').change(function(){
    //Logic here
    var Row   = $("#node-0"),
        Cells = Row.find("td"),
        size  = parseInt(Cells.eq(2).text(), 10),
        chr= $("#filler").val(),
        fillertxt="";

    for (var i=0; i < size ; i++) {
      fillertxt+=chr+chr+" ";
    }

    if(!/[0123456789abcdef]/ig.test(chr)) {
         alert("Do use Hexadecimal characters!");   
    }else{
         $('#input').val(fillertxt);
    }
});
```

Also, it looks like you are trying to use a string in the `for` loop as number of iterations. You either need to parse it as a number, or if it's the strings length, use `length` ?

Comment: I got it correct. It was the problem with textContent. Now it works upto mark. The same code for firefox, too works for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery you might as well use it all the way to ensure cross browser compatibility. Also make sure that you call the `.change` inside the document ready function (which `$(function(){...})`  will ensure)

```
$(function(){
    $('#filler').change(function(){
      var size = parseInt($("#node-0 td:nth-child(3)").text(),10),
          chr = $(this).val(),
          fillertxt="";

      for (var i=0;i<size;i += 1) {
        fillertxt+=chr+chr+" ";
      }

      if(!/[0123456789abcdef]/ig.test(chr)) {
        alert("Do use Hexadecimal characters!");   
      } else {
        $('#input').val(fillertxt);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: ...except that you changed everything *except* the `innerText` which was the one causing the problem.